# How to fix boot error caused by dual-boot with Windows 7 and MacOS X Lion

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot, partitioning, backup

I have a MacBook with an HD of 750 GB; it was partitioned in two parts: the first partition included MacOS X Lion and was about 650 GB; in the second one there was MS Windows 7, with only about 100 GB for the entire system.

Now, I need a bigger partition for Windows. I used the backup creator included in Windows 7, and I obtained a .vhd file. After the backup, I erased everything from the computer, reinstalled OS X and used Disk Utility in order to repartition the HD. Now, the partitions are two: the first (with OSX) of about 250 GB, and the second was of the same size of the one which contained Windows (about 100 GB), formatted in NTFS.

Using the command qemu-img, included in QEMU, I converted the .vhd file in a raw .img file, mounted this file in OS X, and used the dd command in order to copy the first partition of the .img file to the 100 GB partition.

Everything seemed gone fine. I reboot, and using rEFIt (previously installed), I selected the Windows partition. I get an error:

[image: Error 0xc0000225]

I tried to use the Installation disk of Windows 7 to repair what was wrong. Without success...

I also tried a lot of method to repair the boot loader of Windows, like [this](https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc0000225/) or also [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html). But without results...

IMHO, the problem could be linked to the new hardware configuration, like something written in the Windows partition, that was copied (but not correctly updated) in the new partition.

Please, help me! How can I reuse my Windows partition without losing data???

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you need to re-create the [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) upon which both the Mac and Windows rely to boot Windows. You can do this with `gdisk` (from OS X, Linux, or Windows, but you'll need to manually install it in most of these -- see the hybrid MBR link) or by using the `gptsync` program that comes with rEFIt or its maintained offshoot, [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) (Note that rEFInd's `gptsync` has been updated compared to the version that comes with rEFIt.)